What the exact nuance of あれだけに言っておきながら

「この前の―高速道路の件もそうだし、あれだけ天道大洋のことでこちらに言っておきながら動きが遅いんじゃないかしら」

The context is the following: She's drilling her underling from the SCOUTING UNIT being slow on updating the website with the recent dangerous spots apparitions.  "天道大洋のこと" refers to a recent incident that happened that got the whole unit in a panic and  her group (こちら) the "hunting unit".
Their answer is this:

調査次第すぐに追加をいつもはしているんですが、その…例の件でてんやわんやになってしまって

んじゃないかしら here I assume it's just akin to "Isn't it" but I'm a bit stumbled on the exact nuance of あれだけに言っておきながら which seems to have a specific nuance?
I assume the sentence can be read as "You guys talked to us so much with the 天道大洋のことand yet aren't you very slow right now"?

There is no に after あれだけ.

This あれだけ means "that much", and it's interchangeable with あんなに in this context. あれだけ is already an adverbial expression, so don't put any particle (such as に) after だけ. See: interpretting よくこれだけの言い訳が出るものだ

あれだけ天道大洋のことでこちらに言っておきながら、動きが遅いんじゃないかしら
= 天道大洋のことであれだけこちらに言っておきながら、動きが遅いんじゃないかしら
Although they've said that much to us about Taiyo Tendo, aren't they slow?
For all they've said to us about Taiyo Tendo, isn't their response slow?

